# Java object instantiation with fields

Tags: java, object, instantiation

Can we initialize fields of a class in the same line as instantiating it?

```
public class LinkedQueueOfStrings {

    private Node first;
    private Node last;

    private class Node
    {
        private String element;
        private Node next;
    }

    public void enqueue(String s)
    {
        last.next = new Node(){element = s};
        //Is there a way  can do like this??
    }

}
```

Is there a way we can we do like this,

```
last.next = new Node(){first = s};
```

assuming we don't have a constructor which initializes node with an element?

Comment: Not really, and a `String` isn't a `Node`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this (if `s` is final):

```
last.next = new Node() {{element = s;}};
```

which is equivalent to:

```
last.next = new Node() {
    {
        element = s;
    }
};
```

which is an anonymous class with an initializer (effectively a constructor).

But that can cause problems later - for example the object won't be of type `Node`, it will be of type `LinkedQueueOfString$1` (or whatever the anonymous class gets called) which *extends* `Node`.

You should probably just write a constructor, or set the fields separately:

```
last.next = new Node();
last.next.element = s;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that proper way to implement that you want is to provide respective constructor:

```
private static class Node {
        public Node(String element, Node next) {
            this.element = element;
            this.next = next;
        }

        private String element;
        private Node next;
    }
```

or if you have *many fields* to initialize you can use [Builder pattern](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2). 
Also note that your `Node` class can be `static` because it doesn't need enclosing class instance and just takes excess memory.